# sum result from different tables, return null if not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new in MySQL and have problem in one of my query right now. I have 3 tables (user, branch and sales). I want to query and return result of sum of sales group by user and view the result as NULL if the sales not exist. Below is details of my tables:

user

```
user_id username
----------------
1       adam   
2       david
3       siva
```

branch

```
branch_id   user_id
-------------
001         1       
002         1       
003         1
004         2
005         3
```

sales

```
branch_id   sales
-------------
001        20       
002        30       
003        10
```

below is my query;

```
SELECT u.username, SUM(s.sales) AS total_sales
FROM USER u
INNER JOIN branch b ON u.user_id=b.user_id
INNER JOIN sales s ON s.branch_id=b.branch_id
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hint: `left join`.

Comment: A branch can only have 1 user but a user can have many branchs. Odd.

Comment: what so odd about that?

Comment: Consider if branch 3 had no sales your query would would return a sales figure for user 1 even though he has failed to make any sales in branch 3.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.username, SUM(s.sales) AS total_sales
FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN branch b ON u.user_id=b.user_id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.branch_id=b.branch_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.id, SUM(IFNULL(s.sales,0)) AS total_sales
FROM USER u
left JOIN branch b ON u.user_id=b.user_id
left JOIN sales s ON s.branch_id=b.branch_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```